# Can't run python program from command prompt even though python 3.9 is installed

Tags: python, windows-10, command-prompt, python-3.9

[Command prompt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Uh8bmewvpwsLu77cBZSAejb3ue_UEAAa/view?usp=sharing)

I tried to run this python code:

```
#two brown number are an ordered pair in the form (m; n) such that n!+1=m^2
from math import factorial as fact
m=2
n=2
for i in range(10**2): # range of values to check
    # checks current values and changes them according to results
    if (fact(n)+1)==m**2:
        print(m,n)
        m+=1
        n+=1
    elif (fact(n)+1)<m**2:
        n+=1
    elif (fact(n)+1)>m**2:
        m+=1
```

from the command prompt but it showed me the message on the image above, even though I already installed python 3.9 from the official website.

[The python stuff I installed](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Uh8bmewvpwsLu77cBZSAejb3ue_UEAAa/view?usp=sharing)

Anyone knows how to fix this or do I have to reinstall python from the Microsoft Store?

Comment: The image is not visible

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Edit your question to include the relevant information as text.

Comment: You should use the full python installation path or try with `py program.py`

Comment: why are you running `python brown scriptname.py` try using `python scriptname.py`, just `scriptname.py` or `py scriptname.py`

Comment: If you installed cpython did you tick the PATH box. It's also unticked in the image ... https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html

Answer (score 1):

Rename your file containing the code.
**There must not** be spaces and then use the command:

`python3 filename.py`

Answer (score 1):

To call files with spaces use the quotation marks around them.
`python ".\brown numbers.py"`

Generally, it is better to avoid spaces in files names, but sometimes it is unavoidable. In such situations you must explicitly tell Python what is the full file name.

To check if Python is installed correctly run:
`python --version`